# How to convert a unicode list to a list containing python dictionary in python 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Here is list containing dictionary

```
[{u'alpha2_code': u'AX', u'alpha3_code': u'ALA', u'name': u'\ufffd\ufffdland Islands'},{u'alpha2_code': u'AL', u'alpha3_code': u'ALB',u'name':u'Albania'},{u'alpha2_code':u'DZ',u'alpha3_code': u'DZA', u'name': u'Algeria'},{u'alpha2_code': u'AS', u'alpha3_code': u'ASM', u'name': u'American Samoa'}]
```

I want to remove `'u` from each key/value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I don't know why you want to convert your (key, value) pairs into string, but here is a simple solution.
In this function, I'm creating a new list and encode each (key, value) pair into an ascii string.

```
def change_type(lst):
    new_list= []
    for dic in lst:
        new_dic = {}
        for k, v in dic.iteritems():
            new_dic[k.encode("ascii","ignore")] = v.encode("ascii","ignore")
        new_list.append(new_dic)
    return new_list
```

Note that you have a value of `"\ufffd\ufffdland Islands"` which contains unicode characters. So, you have to remove these characters and this function should work. Here is how your list should be:

```
>>> lst = [ {u'alpha2_code': u'AX', u'alpha3_code': u'ALA', u'name': u'land Islands'},
    {u'alpha2_code': u'AL', u'alpha3_code': u'ALB', u'name': u'Albania'},
    {u'alpha2_code': u'DZ', u'alpha3_code': u'DZA', u'name': u'Algeria'},
    {u'alpha2_code': u'AS', u'alpha3_code': u'ASM', u'name': u'American Samoa'}]

>>> new_list = change_type(lst)
>>> new_list
[{'alpha2_code': 'AX', 'alpha3_code': 'ALA', 'name': 'land Islands'},
 {'alpha2_code': 'AL', 'alpha3_code': 'ALB', 'name': 'Albania'}, 
 {'alpha2_code': 'DZ', 'alpha3_code': 'DZA', 'name': 'Algeria'},
 {'alpha2_code': 'AS', 'alpha3_code': 'ASM', 'name': 'American Samoa'}]
```

Comment: @Anwarvic ..Thanks for solution, its working for this small list, i am trying to compare web service response from unicode to non-unicode to compare with list which is also non-unicode string. This code shows another error if i pass long list dictionary,  in given link (data.json file name) https://files.fm/u/bqpftr9g?k=5c126f07         Error is UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I solved the problem by passing ignore in encode method..Thanks